# Android using TCP between 2 simulators

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I have two apps a TCP server and a client app. I have to use `redir add tcp:5000:6000` to get the client to talk to the server. but if I try to load the apps on two actual devices the client fails because it can't connect.

How can I get the two apps on the two different devices to talk to each other like the simulator? 
This is what I'm using for TCP
[TCP EXAMPLE APP](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/)

Comment: do you need something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994759/how-to-receive-incoming-messages-using-smack-lib-on-xmpp ?

Comment: Thanks but thats for xampp I'm trying to have two android devices talk to each other

Comment: not xAmpp but SMACK lib on XMPP which is intended to make a chat and even chatrooms between devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Client.java file change the following two lines...

```
private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";
```

`SERVERPORT` needs to be the same number as that in the `Server.java` file, i.e., 6000.

`SERVER_IP` needs to be the actual IP address of the Android device running the server app.

Comment: THANK YOU! I just figured it out and went back here to post the answer but you beat me! :)